# Two similar codes: One's working, the other isn't

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

I have been messing around with the BGE and it's Python funcions. I modified two scripts in the same way, though one of them is not working somehow.
In this first script, which is working; look at the 'steering' section:

```
    #########################################
#
#   Powertrain.py  Blender 2.6
#
#   tutorial can be found at
#
#   www.tutorialsforblender3d.com
#
#   Released under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.   
#
#   If you use this code, please include this information header.
#
##########################################

#import bge
import bge
import math

# Main Program
def main():

    # get the current controller
    controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

    # get vehicle constraint ID
    vehicleID = ConstraintID(controller)

    # brakes
    brakes = Brakes(vehicleID, controller)

    # gas & reverse
    Power( vehicleID, controller, brakes)

    # steering
    Steering(vehicleID, controller)


########################################################  Vehicle ID

# get vehicle constraint ID
def ConstraintID(controller):

    # get car the controller is attached to
    car = controller.owner

    # get saved vehicle Constraint ID
    vehicleID = car["vehicleID"]

    return vehicleID

########################################################  Brakes

def Brakes(vehicleID, controller):

    # set braking amount
    brakeAmount = 40.0      # front and back brakes
    ebrakeAmount = 100.0    # back brakes only  

    # get sensors
    reverse = controller.sensors["Reverse"]     # sensor named "Reverse"
    brake = controller.sensors["Brake"]         # sensor named "Brake
    emergency = controller.sensors["EBrake"]    # sensor named "EBrake"

    # emergency brakes      
    if emergency.positive == True:

        front_Brake = 0.0
        back_Brake = ebrakeAmount
        brakes = True

    # brake
    elif brake.positive == True and reverse.positive == False:

        front_Brake = brakeAmount
        back_Brake = brakeAmount
        brakes = True

    # no brakes
    else:

        front_Brake = 0.0
        back_Brake = 0.0
        brakes = False

    # brakes    
    vehicleID.applyBraking( front_Brake, 0)
    vehicleID.applyBraking( front_Brake, 1)
    vehicleID.applyBraking( back_Brake, 2)
    vehicleID.applyBraking( back_Brake, 3)

    return brakes

##########################################  Gas & Reverse 

# gas and reverse   
def Power( vehicleID, controller, brakes):  

    # set power amounts
    reversePower = 200.0
    gasPower = 1350.0

    # get power sensors
    gas = controller.sensors["Gas"]             # sensor named "Gas"
    reverse = controller.sensors["Reverse"]     # sensor named "Reverse"

    # brakes
    if brakes == True:

        power = 0.0

    # reverse
    elif reverse.positive == True:

        power = reversePower

    # gas pedal 
    elif gas.positive == True:

        power = -gasPower

    # no gas and no reverse
    else:

        power = 0.0

    # apply power
    vehicleID.applyEngineForce( power, 0)
    vehicleID.applyEngineForce( power, 1)
    vehicleID.applyEngineForce( power, 2)
    vehicleID.applyEngineForce( power, 3)                                       


##################################################  Steering 

def Steering( vehicleID, controller):

    # get speed
    car = controller.owner
    speed = (car.localLinearVelocity.y) * .77
    steer = 0.1299373 - (0.001902582 * speed) + (math.pow((0.00000512896 * speed), 2))

    if speed > 60:
        steer = 0.017

    else:
        steer = steer

    # set turn amount
    turn = 1 * steer

    # get steering sensors
    steerLeft = controller.sensors["Left"]      # sensor named "Left"
    steerRight = controller.sensors["Right"]    # sensor named "Right"

    # turn left 
    if steerLeft.positive == True:

        turn = turn

    # turn right    
    elif steerRight.positive == True:

        turn = -turn

    # go straight   
    else:
        turn = 0.0

    # steer with front tires only
    vehicleID.setSteeringValue(turn,0)
    vehicleID.setSteeringValue(turn,1)


###############################################

# run main program
main()
```

The second one here is built up the same way. Look at the grip section. It isn't working. The script is not functioning at all because of this section:

```
    #########################################
#
#   Suspension.py  Blender 2.6
#
#   tutorial can be found at
#
#   www.tutorialsforblender3d.com
#
#   Released under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.   
#
#   If you use this code, please include this information header.
#
##########################################

import bge

def main():

    # get the current controller
    controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

    # get vehicle constraint ID
    vehicleID = ConstraintID(controller)

    # set tire grip
    Tire_Grip(vehicleID)

    # set suspension compression
    Suspension_Compression(vehicleID)

    # set suspension damping
    Suspension_Damping(vehicleID)

    # set suspension stiffness
    Suspension_Stiffness(vehicleID)

    # set roll influence
    Roll_Influence(vehicleID)

#########################################################

# get vehicle constraint ID
def ConstraintID(controller):

    # get car the controller is attached to
    carObj = controller.owner

    # get saved vehicle Constraint ID
    vehicleID = carObj["vehicleID"]

    return vehicleID


##########################################################

# set tire grip
def Tire_Grip(vehicleID, controller):

    carObj = controller.owner
    speed = carObj.localLinearVelocity.y

    grip = 22 + (-0.315 * speed)

    if EBrake == True:
        grip = 7

    else:
        grip = grip

    GripAmount = 1 * grip

    grip_0 = GripAmount
    grip_1 = GripAmount
    grip_2 = GripAmount
    grip_3 = GripAmount

    vehicleID.setTyreFriction(grip_0, 0)  # front driver's tire 
    vehicleID.setTyreFriction(grip_1, 1)  # front passenger's tire 
    vehicleID.setTyreFriction(grip_2, 2)  # rear driver's tire
    vehicleID.setTyreFriction(grip_3, 3)  # rear passenger's tire

##########################################################

# set suspendion compression
def Suspension_Compression(vehicleID):

    compression_0 = 8.0     # front driver's tire 
    compression_1 = 8.0     # front passenger's tire 
    compression_2 = 8.0     # rear driver's tire
    compression_3 = 8.0     # rear passenger's tire

    vehicleID.setSuspensionCompression(compression_0, 0)  # front driver's tire 
    vehicleID.setSuspensionCompression(compression_1, 1)  # front passenger's tire 
    vehicleID.setSuspensionCompression(compression_2, 2)  # rear driver's tire
    vehicleID.setSuspensionCompression(compression_3, 3)  # rear passenger's tire 


##########################################################

# set suspension damping
def Suspension_Damping(vehicleID):

    damp_0 = 6.0     # front driver's tire 
    damp_1 = 6.0     # front passenger's tire 
    damp_2 = 6.0     # rear driver's tire
    damp_3 = 6.0     # rear passenger's tire

    vehicleID.setSuspensionDamping(damp_0, 0)  # front driver's tire 
    vehicleID.setSuspensionDamping(damp_1, 1)  # front passenger's tire 
    vehicleID.setSuspensionDamping(damp_2, 2)  # rear driver's tire
    vehicleID.setSuspensionDamping(damp_3, 3)  # rear passenger's tire 


###########################################################

# set suspension stiffness
def Suspension_Stiffness(vehicleID):

    stiffness_0 = 112.5     # front driver's tire 
    stiffness_1 = 112.5     # front passenger's tire 
    stiffness_2 = 112.5     # rear driver's tire
    stiffness_3 = 112.5     # rear passenger's tire

    vehicleID.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness_0, 0)  # front driver's tire 
    vehicleID.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness_1, 1)  # front passenger's tire 
    vehicleID.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness_2, 2)  # rear driver's tire
    vehicleID.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness_3, 3)  # rear passenger's tire 

############################################################

# set roll influence
def Roll_Influence(vehicleID):

    roll_0 = 0.06     # front driver's tire 
    roll_1 = 0.06     # front passenger's tire 
    roll_2 = 0.06     # rear driver's tire
    roll_3 = 0.06     # rear passenger's tire

    vehicleID.setRollInfluence( roll_0, 0)  # front driver's tire 
    vehicleID.setRollInfluence( roll_1, 1)  # front passenger's tire 
    vehicleID.setRollInfluence( roll_2, 2)  # rear driver's tire
    vehicleID.setRollInfluence( roll_3, 3)  # rear passenger's tire 


###########################################################
# run main program
main()
```

Does anyone know why only the first script is working with this buildup?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I just found the answer. In the def (main): list. The section of the grip for the tires was set to: Tire_Grip(vehicleID)
In my modification of that section I had to use a controller, so in that section itself it already was: Tire_Grip(vehicleID, controller) while that line in the def (main) was still witout the controller.

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -3):

Get rid of

```
else:
    grip = grip
```

**EDIT:**  Anybody that has programmed for any length of time realizes that you don't need the statement grip = grip. It's redundant. You've already defined what grip is a couple lines above. There's no need to redefine itself *as itself.*  Leave it at a simple if-then statement; there's no need for the else.

Comment: Just as I have commented on your previous answes, please give an explanation of *why* what you're suggesting is the answer. Giving a more detailed explanation may help people understand the issue better and avoid it in future. At the minute they have solution (if this is the correct answer), but no reasoning.

Comment: I already stated "why."  Someone deleted that portion.  This should have been more of a comment than an answer, but they don't let you put code in comments.

Comment: Well, if it's been deleted then add the information to your answer. If you think it should have been a comment then I'm sure "Get rid of the `else: grip = grip` portion" would have been sufficient.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 if someone had erased something from your response, a label appears that has been edited x time ago, you could check the edition and we will know who to report for doing something bad, you should put the reason for your answer

Comment: even if you intulle it, assume things is bad practice because one assumes what he understands by deductions without solid foundations, when one should understand the basics of the answer